# Correctly loading and animating the transition between view controllers

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm developing an app that needs to load a certain view controller if a parameter is valid, and another different view controller if it is not.

I have both view controllers associated to scenes in storyboard.

I'd like to animate the transition between their views **and**,
 given that it is not only a transition between views but their view controllers as well,

I wrote this in an method in `AppDelegate`:

```
UIViewController *previousController = self.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *currentController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"typeAController"];

[UIView transitionFromView:previousController.view
                        toView:self.currentController.view
                      duration:1.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        self.window.rootViewController = currentController;
                    }];
```

1. This seems to work, but I'm not sure if this is the most appropiate way to manage this scenario... is it?
2. Should I take into account any memory management implications if I do this way?

I'm targeting iOS 7.0 and above.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please put a screen shot of storyboard.

Comment: According  to the Docs "This method modifies the views in their view hierarchy only. It does not modify your application’s view controllers in any way. For example, if you use this method to change the root view displayed by a view controller, it is your responsibility to update the view controller appropriately to handle the change." You are doing it in the completion block.So you should be fine

Comment: Have you connected the scenes by segue.

Comment: Every time if you write `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` every time it will create a new object.

Comment: If you have multiple segues in the storyboard, you can simply call the correct segue using its identifier for the transition to happen - based on your condition.

Comment: @ArpitParekh I can only set one segue in storyboard (of type "embed")

Comment: @lostInTransit I can only set one "embed" segue in storyboard

Comment: I have not much idea upon embed type and in how many segues can we set from one view controller to another. Need to do work still.